# Why can I see a bcc recipient in a received e-mail?

Tags: email, thunderbird, bcc

I'm quite confused about this.
I received an email today where the bcc recipient is visible:
[image]

Header:

```
Return-Path: xxxxxxx
Received: from xxxx ([xxxx]) by xxxxx (xxxx)
 with ESMTPS (Nemesis) id xxxxx for <xxxxx>;
 Wed, 06 May 2015 12:59:47 +0200
Received: from [xxxxx] (port=4696)
    by xxxxx with esmtp (Exim 4.82_1-5b7a7c0-XX)
    (envelope-from <xxxx>)
    id xxxxx
    for xxxxx; Wed, 06 May 2015 12:59:45 +0200
Received: from xxxxx [xxxxx] by xxxxx with xxxx(xxxxx);
 06 May 2015 10:59:45 UT
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============0674811891=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: xxxxx
To: xxxxx
bcc: bxxxx@xxxx
Date: Wed, 06 May 2015 12:59:44 +0200
Subject: Rechnung Online Kunden P
Envelope-To: <xxxx>
```

How is that possible? If Thunderbird has recognized this meta-data correctly, then it should have been sent the right way (and I, or Thunderbird   respectively wouldn't see it), shouldn't it?

Comment: Is the BCC addressed to you by any chance?

Comment: Nope ^^ the bcc-adress does not belong to me or is set up in my thunderbird, it's foreign.
It belongs to the same domain as the senders adress.

Comment: That's odd, have you communicated with this sender in the past? Do you know if their mail server has changed or if they've made any obvious configuration changes? This sounds like a mail server issue on their end...

Comment: This is from a shop where I made my first order a few days ago. In the header of the (first) confirmation mail I cannot see any BCC adresses, but there might were none. This example is the second email I ever received from this shop. 
A mail server issue sounds legit, but I cannot imagine why this data seems to work in a way that thunderbird can show it to me, but otherweise not works because thunderbird can show it to me...

Comment: It's not up to Thunderbird to shield you from seeing a BCC address. The mail server should have taken care of this prior to sending. Thunderbird is merely programmed to parse and display the header data as it is received.

Comment: The header data which the server sent is kind of like the freedom of speech: You are free to say anything and everything but it does not make you immune to the consequences.

Comment: Okay so, the outgoing mail server should have cleaned the mail header bevor sending the mail to my mailhoster and thunderbird only shows what it gets. You may post an answer to be accepted.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, 32bitfloat, you need to ping with the at symbol. I've already done it in this post so MonkeyZeus can see your message about moving his comment to an answer!